# How can i parse JSON string in c# Get error Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {“name”:“value”})

Tags: c#, json

I tried the following code but am not able to parse json sting. When
I am parsing I am getting this error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {“name”:“value”}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1

```
   HiddenField1.Value = "{\"AlertDataList\":[{\"header\":\"YTD Noresp 04/01/2010 &#45; 01/31/2011 Created On 10/02/2013\",\"type\":\"High      \",\"NoResponse\":\"0\",\"NoResponsePct\":\"      0.00&#37;\",\"Response\":\"1\",\"ResponsePct\":\"    100.00&#37;\",\"All\":\"1\",\"accountperiodid\":\"11306\",\"navigateUrl\":\"windowpane://Insights.exe/HCI.Insights.Windows.Forms.Converted.FormFinalert…&responseType=NoResp&accountPeriodId=11306&alertType=High&hasResponses=All\",\"navigateResponsesUrl\":\"windowpane://Insights.exe/HCI.Insights.Windows.Forms.Converted.FormFinalert…responseType=NoResp&accountPeriodId=11306&alertType=High&hasResponses=Resp\",\"navigateNoResponsesUrl\":\"windowpane://Insights.exe/HCI.Insights.Windows.Forms.Converted.FormFinalert…D&responseType=NoResp&accountPeriodId=11306&alertType=High&hasResponses=No Resp\"},{\"header\":\"YTD Noresp 04/01/2010 &#45; 01/31/2011 Created On 10/02/2013\",\"type\":\"Medium\",\"NoResponse\":\"0\",\"NoResponsePct\":\"      0.00&#37;\",\"Response\":\"1\",\"ResponsePct\":\"    100.00&#37;\",\"All\":\"1\",\"accountperiodid\":\"11306\",\"navigateUrl\":\"windowpane://Insights.exe/HCI.Insights.Windows.Forms.Converted.FormFinalert…esponseType=NoResp&accountPeriodId=11306&alertType=Medium&hasResponses=All\",\"navigateResponsesUrl\":\"windowpane://Insights.exe/HCI.Insights.Windows.Forms.Converted.FormFinalert…sponseType=NoResp&accountPeriodId=11306&alertType=Medium&hasResponses=Resp\",\"navigateNoResponsesUrl\":\"windowpane://Insights.exe/HCI.Insights.Windows.Forms.Converted.FormFinalert…responseType=NoResp&accountPeriodId=11306&alertType=Medium&hasResponses=No Resp\"},{\"header\":\"YTD Noresp 04/01/2010 &#45; 01/31/2011 Created On 10/02/2013\",\"type\":\"All\",\"NoResponse\":\"0\",\"NoResponsePct\":\"      0.00&#37;\",\"Response\":\"2\",\"ResponsePct\":\"    100.00&#37;\",\"All\":\"2\",\"accountperiodid\":\"11306\",\"navigateUrl\":\"windowpane://Insights.exe/HCI.Insights.Windows.Forms.Converted.FormFinalert…D&responseType=NoResp&accountPeriodId=11306&alertType=All&hasResponses=All\",\"navigateResponsesUrl\":\"windowpane://Insights.exe/HCI.Insights.Windows.Forms.Converted.FormFinalert…&responseType=NoResp&accountPeriodId=11306&alertType=All&hasResponses=Resp\",\"navigateNoResponsesUrl\":\"windowpane://Insights.exe/HCI.Insights.Windows.Forms.Converted.FormFinalert…TD&responseType=NoResp&accountPeriodId=11306&alertType=All&hasResponses=No Resp\"}]}"


    public void AlertTable()
    {           
        List<alertMain> json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <List<alertMain>>((HiddenField1.Value).ToString());          

    }

public class alert
{
    [JsonProperty("header")]
    public string header { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("NoResponse")]
    public string NoResponse { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("NoResponsePct")]
    public string NoResponsePct { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Response")]
    public string Response { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ResponsePct")]
    public string ResponsePct { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("All")]
    public string All { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("accountperiodid")]
    public string accountperiodid { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("navigateUrl")]
    public string navigateUrl { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("navigateResponsesUrl")]
    public string navigateResponsesUrl { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("navigateNoResponsesUrl")]
    public string navigateNoResponsesUrl { get; set; }        
}

public class alertMain
{
    [JsonProperty("AlertDataList")]
    public List<alert> AlertDataList { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why do you convert to `List<alertMain>`?
Try `alertMain` since it is already containing the list of alerts.

Comment: I've posted it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change hidden field value from

```
HiddenField1.Value = "{\"AlertDataList\":[{...}]}"
```

to

```
HiddenField1.Value = "[{\"AlertDataList\":[{...}]}]"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're deserializing to a `List<alertMain>`, yet your JSON contains simply one `alertMain`.

Try:

```
alertMain json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<alertMain>((HiddenField1.Value).ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

*Answer from my comment.*

You are trying to convert `List<alertMain>`. `alertMain` already contains a list.

Try using just `alertMain` since it is already containing the list of alerts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast your json into `List<IDictionary<string,string>>` this will should be work.

PFB code.

```
public void AlertTable()
{
            var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>((HiddenField1.Value).ToString());

}
```

and you just create a one class like below:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<IDictionary<string, string>> AlertDataList { get; set; }
}
```